# undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'

Tags: c++, boost, g++, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to compile a code and I get the error

> undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length`

I use g++ in Ubuntu 12.04. Although I have done some C++ programming I am new to the Linux development environment (used only IDEs previously).

So I did a basic search for this trouble, and found about some linking issues. I didn't quite understand them as I am a newbie. Reading some of those solutions confused me further. My boost library folder is in `/usr/include`. Some solutions says that it should be in `/usr/lib`. But I don't have any boost folder there.

What do I need to change?

Comment: open a terminal and write `updatedb && locate libboost_program_options`. that will find the path where you installed the lib files for boost.

Comment: locate libboost_program_options doesnt return anything but as I said boost folder is there in /usr/include and that also has a folder program options

Comment: OOps sorry just saw that edit now.Ran that command and got this errorupdatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db

Comment: might need sudo.. you can also locate the file with the `find` command, but I find the `locate` command to be much easier to use. the `updatedb` command simply updates the database that `locate` uses

Comment: I have MATLAB installed.Now that locate command shows that file is in /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libboost_program_options.so.1.40.0

Comment: @Picowhat sudo apt install libboost-all-dev

Answer (score 40):

If you have installed boost from repo just use `-lboost_program_options` that will suffice.
If you installed boost libraries in some other library, you need to specify that directoty by `-L/path/to/lib`

In CMake you may specify `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lboost_program_options")`

However with CMake you should use

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(target ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I have installed from the repo,but the -lboost_program_options gives me an error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options

Comment: In CMake you should use `find_package(Boost ...` to locate Boost and use `target_link_libraries` to specify libraries; this helps when porting to other compilers / OS.

Comment: well in my system just `-lboost_program_options` works. @user1633316: you can do a search for `libboost-* ` files. give that path with `-L` on note did you install program options from repo ?

Comment: From repo I have installed libboost 1.46-dev,Now installing libboost 1.46-dev ALL

Comment: Actually boost is there in /usr/include.and I have given the L flag to that -L usr/include/boost/program_options

Comment: `usr/include/boost/` is where headers are. you need to specify the lib path

Comment: @user1633316 you located the lib files with the `locate` command, like I showed you. that's the path that you need to include. more information is provided [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library)

Comment: Yes I located it and the problem is solved.Thanks now I will have to do the same for other libraries also like uhd.

Comment: For OSX with MacPorts boost libraries, use -lboost_program_options-mt

Comment: It wasn't working for me, I had to add a minimum version number. `FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.40 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)`

Comment: Fixed this on Ubuntu 14.04 only after installing libboost1.55-all-dev

Answer (score 6):

There were changes to the `<string>` class in the C++11 standard which may conflict with versions of the Boost library that were compiled with a non-C++11 compiler (such as G++-4.8). Try recompiling boost or using a version of C++ compiler that was used to compile your Boost libraries.

Comment: This brought me on the right track! I needed to compile my stuff with `g++-5` instead of `g++-4.8`. It's probably not good that Ubuntu 16.04 has `g++-4.8` as default `g++` compiler while the C++ libraries it delivers are obviously compiled via `g++-5`.

Answer (score 3):

Also double check that the setting of the pre-processor variable `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` is identical to the setting of the variable that was used for compiling boost. The default setting of the variable may be different depending on the Linux distribution and version of the GNU compiler used.

See [Dual ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and struggled for a looong time and nothing worked... but the fix was very simple.

First, execute `apt install libboost-all-dev`. After this is completed, executing `whereis libboost_program_options` should yield an output similar to

`libboost_program_options: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a`

Once this is done (and I know this is silly but) make sure, to link the libraries in the correct order, i.e. after your source files.

In my case, I was executing `g++ -lboost_program_options main.cpp` instead of `g++ main.cpp -lboost_program_options` and NOTHING worked, not a single fix I could find (and I had the exact error as mentioned in the post). That's two days in my life wasted and I truly hope somebody will stumble across this reply and save themselves some trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Where are the boost libraries (files ending in .so and .a)? Find those, then add this to your link command: -L/path/to/boost/libs -lname-of-boost-lib

This has to be the most common problem people face when first starting c++. There are probably a thousand other undefined reference questions on SO. Just search for undefined reference.

Answer (score 0):

The libraries are normally installed into `/usr/lib` (e.g. on my system, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0`).

In order to compile code that is going to link with those libraries, you normally use the header files, provided in `/usr/include`.

Unlike many libraries, Boost doesn't come with pkg-config files, so you need to add the linker flags yourself.  With the usual Makefile rules, you'll need something like `LDLIBS += -lboost_program_options`.

Note also that, although the `libboost-dev` package provides the headers for `program_options`, you need also to install `libboost-program-options-dev` to get the corresponding library.