# c++ and boost program_options error: 'desc' does not name a type

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial on boost program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html), but I'm getting this error:

error: 'desc' does not name a type.

Here is the source code I have:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

using namespace std;

namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("compression", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

the error is on the line starting with 'desc.add_options', not the line where I construct it.

/usr/local/boost is my BOOST_ROOT, and I have it added to my code blocks compiler settings.  The compiler arg is -I/usr/local/boost

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you try to use the lines

```
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
```

on top level outside of all functions. In C++ this does not work - move this code to a function.

Comment: I put it in the main method, now I am getting a whole lot more errors: undefined reference to 'boost::program_options:options_description::m_default_line_length'.  I must still be missing something, I have no idea what.

Comment: You need to link with program_options. In gcc that would be -lboost_program_options.

Comment: the boost instructions just said I need to have the boost directory given by -I/usr/local/boost, where I installed it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179154/undefined-reference-to-boostprogram-optionsoptions-descriptionm-default-l

Comment: ok so in Code::Blocks, I tried adding that to my linker settings tab under "Other linker options", now my build log just says "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options"  and it failed.

Comment: I don't now Code::Blocks, sorry. You should look there for option to add libraries as linker input, and add boost_program_options.

Comment: do you think the problem could have to do with how I installed boost?  I simply downloaded their tarball and untarred it into /usr/local.  Do you think I need to do some kind of 'sudo apt-get install boost' command instead?

Comment: Yes I think it is not only about downloading. Most of boost should be usable after it since only header files are needed. But program_options needs to be build to create the library you link your program with. Try apt-get path.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libboost-dev-all fixed my problem.